# Magento EE: All EE features not loading/partially broke on frontend

Tags: magento-enterprise

Magento EE Latest version.

So, all of the features are enabled (e.g. gift cards) under advanced modules. However, going to the gift card page (on the RWD default theme) shows that none of the fields to, for example, enter the price of the gift card are there. The XML files between how it currently is and that came with it appear to be the same.

Another example: The same thing happens with the rule based product relations (upsells/crossells, etc). It's calling in the view.phtml echo $this->getChildHtml('upsell_products') but that is going to the default upsell block for upsell.phtml (the one found in catalog.xml). If I remove that block from catalog.xml, nothing shows up anymore. The targetrules is the one it's supposed to be calling.

Where do I start?

Obvious things like disabling the cache haven't resolved it

Comment: What is your package?  Do you have a compatible package/theme in your `app/design` folder?  `RWD/default` is community.  The `enterprise/rwd` theme is enterprise.

Comment: frontend/rwd/enterprise... so under configuration -> design it's set to rwd as the package

Comment: Enable template hints and see what theme files are being used.  Are there theme files rolling back to `rwd/default` instead of `rwd/enterprise`?

Comment: yes, e.g. frontend/rwd/default/template/catalog/product/list/upsell.phtml ... I'm guessing I need to set the "default" field to "enterprise"

Comment: submit an answer and I can give you the point for having the correct solution. thank you! that resolved it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set `System -> Configuration -> Design -> Package` to 'rwd'

Set `System -> Configuration -> Design -> Theme` to 'enterprise'.

Comment: in addition, from 1.14 and up, you could add a theme.xml in your theme where you can set the parent template. So in rwd add <parent>enterprise/default</parent>